# how to assign a char value to string variable in c#

Tags: c#

i have a string strText with certain value on it,i need to assign '\0' or charactor  at the specified position of strText.
ie strText[5]='\0'.how is it possible in c#.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Insert method to specify the index. You need to give it a string though, so if you can replace '\0' with "\0" or else just call .ToString()

```
strText = strText.Insert(5, yourChar.ToString());
```

Comment: Note that this would add the character at that position, not replace the character at that position with a new one.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable, so you will need to convert it to a character array, set the character at the specified position, and then convert back to string:

```
char[] characters = "ABCDEFG".ToCharArray ();
characters[5] = '\0';
string foo = new String (characters);
```